# swiftyJSON grab random index from Array

Tags: ios, swift, swifty-json

The array contained in the key "children" contains 100 items.

Is there away to tell SwiftyJSON to grab a random index? I tried creating a random number

```
var random = arc4random_uniform(24)
```

but when I inserted random I got the error:

"Cannot subscript a value of type 'JSON' with an index of type 'UInt32'"

I also converted it to an NSNumber and same thing, I'm completely lost.

```
func getBackgoundImageData(completed: @escaping DownloadComplete) {

    let imageURL = URL(string: IMAGE_URL)!
    Alamofire.request(imageURL).responseJSON { response in

        switch response.result {

        case .success(let value):

            let json = JSON(value)
            if let url = json["data"]["children"][0]["data"]["preview"]["images"][0]["source"]["url"].string {
                self._backgroundImageURL = url
            }

        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
        completed()
    }   
}
```

Comment: In general when you use something like `["data"]["children"][0]["data"]["preview"]["images"][0]["source"]["url"]` you are going to have problems as Swift may not be able to infer the types of all those access correctly.  Split this line out into a series of conditional downcasts `if let data = json["data"] as [String:Any] ...` and so on until you get your final array and then use the random index on that

Answer (score 1):

The `arc4random_uniform` function's input and returned value are both UInt32. Swift is picky about numeric types, and does not silently convert between them like C family languages do. You should cast random ego an Int:

```
var random = Int(arc4random_uniform(24))
```

(And you need to break up your indexing into your data structure as Paul says in his comment.)

Comment: giddy up! honestly I thought I had attempted to cast it as an Int && NSNumber && pretty much any number format...thanks bud :)

Comment: NSNumber is an artifact of the fact that the numeric types are not objects in Objective-C. You can't put numeric values into an `NSArray` without converting them to `NSNumber`s. There is no real reason to use `NSNumber`s in Swift.